# Sharing data between JSP files?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have two JSP files on a GAE project. I'm trying to pass data between them:

**index.jsp**:

```
<%! String title = "foo"; %>
<jsp:include page="templates/header.jsp" />
```

**templates/header.jsp**:

```
<!-- ... -->
<title><%=title%></title>
<!-- ... -->
```

This fails, saying that `title` can't be resolved. What is the right way to do this?

The error is:

> An error occurred at line: 8 in the
>   jsp file: /templates/header.jsp title
>   cannot be resolved

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass data from Java Servlet to JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp)

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way for your existing code to make use of the JSP defined variable is to switch your jsp:include tag for the jsp include directive...

Instead of writing

```
<jsp:include page="templates/header.jsp" />
```

you should change it to:

```
<%@include file="templates/header.jsp" %>
```

The difference in tag works due to how the JSP compiler treats each tag type: Using the directive, as defined above, more or less just tells the compiler to dump the contents of the included file, in your current file, where as the jsp:include tag tells the compiler to process the include file (as a separate entity), and incorporate its output into the current file.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

answer: [Pass data from Java Servlet to JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp/5414654#5414654)