# Loop through an ArrayList in a Servletcontext

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

I got an `arrayList` of `BlogPosts` and I want to show the content of the objects on screen.
I read my `ArrayList` from the `ServletContext` with this output:

```
 [com.example.week3.BlogPost@58d100c8, com.example.week3.BlogPost@5baade52]
```

Where and how do I read the content of this?

This is my BlogPost class:

```
package com.example.week3;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BlogPost implements Serializable{
    private String blogtext;

    public BlogPost(String bt) {
       blogtext = bt;
    }

    public String getBlogtext() {
        return blogtext;
    }

}
```

This is where I store my List

```
Object o = getServletContext().getAttribute("blogpost");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using the default `toString()` method implementation of Object.

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So you are getting output like `com.example.week3.BlogPost@58d100c8`. When you iterate over the `ArrayList` you need to typecast it to your `BlogPosts` Object and use it getter methods or overridden `toString()` to display it's content.

You can do

```
    Object o = getServletContext().getAttribute("blogpost");

    if( o instanceof ArrayList) {
        List blogList = (ArrayList) o;
        for(Object blog : blogList){
            BlogPost blogPost = (BlogPost) blog;
            System.out.println(blogPost.getBlogtext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added my BlogPost class, can you help me out how to display all content of the blogposts?

Comment: Thanks! And can you tell me how I can display the results in my JSP page?

Comment: You can set it in the request as attribute , forward the request to JSP and the access it there. Google `pass data from servlet to JSP`. [Sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp).