# Pass on getGeneratedKeys to next page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, struts2

I would like to pass on the `getGneratedKeys` which is also known as `last_generated_id` from the current Java class to the next class. However, I am quite clueless on how to *store* and *collect* the ID to the next Java class for this class to use.

The scenario is that `insert.jsp` will *insert all the strings and int* into my mysql database. The 2nd page `UserImage.jsp` will *upload the image into the same table and same record* as `insert.jsp`.
This means that `UserImage` query would be an *update* query instead of an insert query.

**`Save.java` (associated class for `insert.jsp`):**

```
public String execute()
{ 
   int i = 0; //SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","8899");

String s = "insert into usertable(userNRIC, userName, userEmail, userPW, userContact, userAddress, catID, catTypeID, sectionID, status"
                        + ") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(s, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ps.setString(1, mb.getUserNRIC());
ps.setString(2, mb.getUserName());
ps.setString(3, mb.getUserEmail());
ps.setString(4, mb.getUserPW());
ps.setInt(5, mb.getUserContact());
ps.setString(6, mb.getUserAddress());
ps.setInt(7, mb.getCatID());
ps.setInt(8, mb.getCatTypeID());
ps.setInt(9, mb.getSectionID());
ps.setString(10, mb.getStatus());       
ps.executeUpdate();
con.commit();
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    i = rs.getInt(1);
    //ps.setInt(i, mb.getUserID("UserID"));
}
    ps.close();
    con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

    }
    return SUCCESS;
    
}
```

**`FileUploadAction.java` (associated class for `UserImage.jsp`):**

```
public String execute(){
    int i = 0;
    connection = getConnection();
    String query = "update usertable set userPhoto=? where userID=?";
    try {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
         //String uniqueFileName = fileToCreate.getPath();
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, this.userImageFileName);
       
        i = pst.executeUpdate();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: what is the user journey? how the pages are navigated?

Comment: @Braj <action name="insert" class="Student.Save">
    <result name="success">/Student/UserImage.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/Student/error.jsp</result>
    </action>    Immediately after the user submits insert.jsp, if success, they will be navigated to the UserImage.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Algo:

```
Record record = Fire the select query based on userID ordered by last insertion
If record is found then
    get the generated value from first record
    update the record
Else
    insert new record
```

---

As per your comment

User Journey : `Student.jsp` -> `UserImage.jsp`

Simply store the auto-generated random key as request attribute and pass it client side to the `UserImage.jsp` and send back to server when upload button is clicked.

Read more about [Pass data from Java Servlet to JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response. However, where do I place these codes? I am a beginner so I have not learnt where to insert such codes. Is it in the sql command? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the action class you should create a property (with getter and setter) to hold the value from `getGeneratedKeys`. Let it be `last_generated_id` which you initialize by the first action.

The action returns `UserImage.jsp` where you can use a [hidden](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/hidden-tag.html) field bound to the action property that contains a value.

When you submit the form to the second action this value is populated to the second action property. So, you can get it easy there when you need to use it when a second action is executed.

Because you use different classes for the actions then you should create this property in both classes. Take care that a hidden field is properly bound and populated by OGNL via providing appropriate actions configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `get last inserted id`while update time.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT max(userID) FROM usertable";
int my_last_generated_id =  stmt.executeQuery(query).uniqueResult();
```

And Your UpdatePost

```
 pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
 pst.setString(1, this.userImageFileName);
 pst.setInt(2, my_last_generated_id );
 i = pst.executeUpdate();
```