# Ajax to display arraylist from the servlet in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a `JSP` page which receives a list from a `servlet` and displays it using `JSTL`.I want to send the request using `ajax`. How to get the list from the `servlet` and display using using `ajax` now.

part of `jsp` page without ajax

```
<form action="StatusServlet" method="post">
 <div class="bfh-datepicker" data-name="datepicker" data-format="d-m-y" data-date="today" data-align="right" id="datepicker">
    </div>


<hr class="soften">
<h5><strong>Screen</strong></h5>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Screen" value="1">
            Screen1
    </label>
</div>
//remaining code here
</form>

<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

        <c:forEach items="${statusdisplay}" var="statuslist">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group  col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Screen</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "${statuslist.screen}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Total Seats A</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.seatsA}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Total Seats B</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.seatsB}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Show</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="${statuslist.show}" readonly>
                    </div><br>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Class A Price</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.priceA}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Class B Price</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.priceB}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Start Time</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.start_time}" readonly>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">End Time</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.end_time}" readonly>
                    </div><br>
                </div>
            </div>

//remaining code code
```

Here is my `servlet` code

```
request.setAttribute("statusdisplay", statuslist);

            RequestDispatcher requestdispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Status.jsp");
            requestdispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

how to send the form data to servlet using ajax and display the received `arraylist` using ajax and jstl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax simple code

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","servlet.do",true);//second param is your servlet url
xmlhttp.send();

//callback
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var result = xmlhttp.responseText; //this is what you want
    }
  }
```

note:
in servlet,you must out.println() what is you want.
this is very easy ajax code, you just know what is ajax!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ajax to show the list.
You have to create a servlet that gets the data and then go to a JSP to show it. You can see an example of sending data from a servlet to a JSP here:

[Pass data from Java Servlet to JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp)