# Passing data from a Java page to JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to pass an Object type from *Java class to Jsp page.*

After going through many sites am bit confused on how to go about with this. My Java file has this content :

```
    Object categoryelements;
    Iterator it=elements.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        JSONObject innerObj= (JSONObject)it.next();
        categoryelements= innerObj.get("category");
        System.out.println(categoryelements);
    }
```

I want to pass this *categoryelements* to JSP page.

Is it possible to do so? Am making use of JSP page, Servlet and a Java page

Can you please provide a solution for this?

Comment: What is the value in `categoryelements`?

Comment: please post your jsp , and please tell us who would call the code you provided in the question

Comment: Have a look at this post which seems to be relevant to your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414600/pass-data-from-java-servlet-to-jsp

Comment: @VPK categoryelements contains string elements. Am using JSONObject as a result of which I assigned it as an Object type.

Comment: @Krithi, then you can directly get the values once you assign it in request attribute, have you tried that?

Comment: My jsp page contains a dropdown list that must be populated with the values from 'categoryelements'. @Amrola

Comment: @VPK Thanks! I just tried doing that. I think I've got it. Can u tell me how to populate that into a dropdownlist of my jsp page

Comment: @Amrola I've created an object in my Servlet code to access the Java page containing 'categoryelements'. Something like this in my Servlet, RetrieveCategory ret=new RetrieveCategory(); request.setAttribute("categoryelements",ret.categoryelements); And in my JSP page I've retrieved like this, <%= request.getAttribute("categoryelements") %> Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: please update your question , and add the source code

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTPRequest object will be having setAttribute, getAttribute & removeAttribute methods, it will internally hold a map `[Map<String,Object>]` to keep the attributes, you can set the key & value pair and get it in the JSP using the implicit request object

Answer (score -1):

If `categoryelements` contains plain string then set the request attribute like this,

```
request.setAttribute("categoryelements", categoryelements.toString());
```

And in `JSP`fetch the value in for example a `div` like this,

```
<div>${categoryelements}</div>
```

**Edit:-**

To access the request attribute in `dropdownlist` you can use the `JSTL` library which is helpful in handling the flow of execution in `JSP` or `HTML`. You can add this library in your `JSP` page like this,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

And then use them to iterate the list as follows,

```
<select name="selectFieldName">
    // following line of code works as Java for loop and here 'listRequestAttribute' can be any list type object e.g. List<String>
    <c:forEach items="${listRequestAttribute}" var="currentListItem">
        // '${currentListItem}' will hold the current object in the loop iteration.
        <option value="${currentListItem}" >
            ${currentListItem}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I've created an object in my Servlet code to access the Java page containing 'categoryelements'. Something like this in my Servlet,     RetrieveCategory ret=new RetrieveCategory();                 request.setAttribute("categoryelements",ret.categoryelements);      And in my JSP page I've retrieved like this,                                               <%= request.getAttribute("categoryelements") %>                                 Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: In my JSP page, this is the code in <body> , <div>${categoryelements}</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Category/Tagg:</td>
            <td><select name="select" required>
               <option value=""> Please select </option>
                <c:forEach var="entry" items="${categoryelements}">
                    <option value="${categoryelements}"> ${categoryelements}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select></td>
        </tr>                                                                                             But the values are not getting populated

Comment: Update- In Servlet:                RetrieveCategory ret=new RetrieveCategory();request.setAttribute("categoryelements",ret.categoryelements);  In JSP :                <div>${categoryelements}</div> <table> <tr> <td> Category/Tagg:</td> <td><select name="select" required> <option value=""> Please select </option> <c:forEach var="entry" items="${categoryelements}"> <option value="${categoryelements}"> ${categoryelements}</option> </c:forEach> </select></td> </tr>

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Inside body of JSP page :

<div>${categoryelements}</div>  // this is where am retrieving the contents of categoryelements as u said
<select name="select" required>
               <option value=""> Please select </option>
                <c:forEach var="entry" items="${categoryelements}">
                    <option value="${categoryelements}"> ${categoryelements}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>

Nothing is printed in the browser. Values are'nt getting populated. 'categoryelements' contains string elements to be populated in the drop down

Comment: Have you tried with `<div><%= request.getAttribute("categoryelements") %></div>`? Also in ` <option value="${categoryelements}"> ${categoryelements}</option>` you should use the loop variable `${entry}` instead of `${categoryelements}`.

Comment: It prints null in the browser :(

Comment: Did you checked if the value of `categoryelements` is printed correctly in the servlet class? And your servlet class have no compilation errors? If not the try to use session instead of request.

Comment: Value of categoryelements is printed as null which means data isn't retrieved in the Servlet. What can be done to rectify that?

Comment: When are you setting the value in the  `categoryelements`? Make sure you set the value properly before setting the request attribute.

Answer (score -1):

in Java:

```
Object categoryelements;
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator it=elements.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    JSONObject innerObj= (JSONObject)it.next();
    result.add(innerObj.get("category"));
}
request.setAttribute("result", result);
```

in JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<jsp:useBean id="result" class="java.lang.List" scope="request" />
...

<c:forEach var="item" items="${result}" >
    <c:out value="${item}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This is just a simple example. You might consider using classes other than `Object` to provide better control over your output. The `Gson` library might help you here.